# Get node IP based on its disk free space

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write an ansible playbook that checks for disk space on multiple servers.

This is my Ansible playbook so far:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Check / freespace
      shell: df -h / | awk '{if($5 > 85)print (IP}'s
```

Basically what I want to do is as soon as the shell condition is met, I want to retrieve the IPs of all those servers that exceed 85%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Ansible fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) `ansible_mounts` to get the list of mounted devices and their details.

This fact will give us:

- total space in `size_total`
- free space in `size_available`

So we can get the percentage of free space with:

```
size_available / size_total x 100 = free space
```

The example task below will show the device if free space is less than 15%:

```yaml
    # Use this task if "gather_facts" is disabled
    - name: collect ansible_mounts facts
      setup:
        filter: ansible_mounts

    - name: Show Devices having less than 15% free space
      debug:
        msg: "Device with > 85% use: {{ item.device }}"
      when: item.size_available / item.size_total * 100 < 15
      loop: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.mount }}"
```

*Update:*

If you'd like to filter out the local device mounts, you could use `regex_search` filter like `not item.device | regex_search('^/dev')` in the `when` condition additionally.

Comment: Quick question, what if i want to output the result to a csv file?

Comment: You could `set_fact` a new variable instead of `debug`, and write the values from the variable to a file with `copy`.

Comment: Thank you. You were super helpful.